# GridView looking similar in every device

Tags: android, gridview, screen-resolution, layoutparams

I need to know how to set the `LayoutParam` according to the resolution of the mobile phones..
Im using a `GridView` where I'm using `GridView.LayoutParams(45, 45)`.. Now if I'm using mobile with small screen size is ok.. But if I test with the big screen device like **HTC Desire HD** then its looking so small.. How to make everything as similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does using android:numColumns or setNumColumns(int numColumns) not work for your needs?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setNumColumns(int)

Answer (score 0):

Divide your display's width in 3 parts (for 3 columns or 4 for 4 columns....)

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
            int width = display.getWidth();  
            int height = display.getHeight();

            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width/3 , width/3));
```